# color tint a complex drawing in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I have a board ful of logos for a creds presentation which has a load of vector logos which are complex shapes. I want to turn then completely monochromatic to a particular shade of dark sepia/grey whilst preserving the tonal detail in the gradients

Is there an easy way to do this? can someone give me a pointer please? There are a lot of them and doing them one by one will be very tedious :-)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use Live Color, or as it's listed in the application, Recolor Artwork.

- Select the art
- Choose Edit > Edit Colors > Recolor Artwork (or click the button on the control bar)
- Choose 1 under "colors"
- Double-click the little color box under "New", the color picker will pop up
- select your grey
- Click OK

[image: live color]

If you want all the items to match the same grey, you could theoretically select all the logos and do this once with them all. No need to do it for each and every piece of art if you want them all to use the same value of grey.